# Как изменять гугл карты

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api, google-maps

Подскажите люди добрые, как я могу  изменения вносит в google карты, которая расположена в iframe ссылкой. Сайт стоит на wp. Нужно что бы легенда все время показывалась. Хотелось бы узнать как можно получить доступ к этому левому элементу. просто прописав #gmap #legendPanel. не получается да и получит iframe
через js никак `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')`.  Я читал про cors, но так и не понял в чем проблема. ссылка на сайт если что [https://lombard.multiweb.ee/contact-us/.](https://lombard.multiweb.ee/contact-us/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Никак.** Никакими силами невозможно через js получить доступ к элементам iframe - это требования безопасности.

Comment: @KAGGDesign и как тогда быть?

Comment: Искать настройки, которые можно передать в iframe. Возможно, таких настроек нет, и идею можно забыть.

Comment: @ вообще не обязательно же только js использовать, я вообще ищу варианты все.

Comment: Я ответил - настройки iframe, если они есть.

Comment: Для этого есть Google Geolocation API получаете ключи дальше пытаетесь что-то сделать)